# Tinkerpop Frames @Adjacency to Orientdb LINKLIST

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop

Is there a way to map Tinkerpop Frames's @Adjacency annotated property to Orientdb LINKLIST? Right now I've something like this:

```
interface Person {
    @Adjacency(label = "personCars", direction = Direction.OUT)
    Iterable<Car> getCars();
    @Adjacency(label = "personCars", direction = Direction.OUT)
    void addCar(Car car);
}
```

I want this to be mapped to LINKLIST in Orientdb database to keep an order of added vertices. But this is by default mapped to LINKBAG type. Is there any clean solution to set Orientdb to map adjacencies to LINKLISTs?

Answer (score 1):

OrientDB, by default, uses a set to handle the edge collection. Sometimes it's better having an ordered list to access the edge by an offset. Example:

```
person.createEdgeProperty(Direction.OUT, "Photos").setOrdered(true);
```

Every time you access the edge collection the edges are ordered. Below is an example to print all the photos in an ordered way.

```
for (Edge e : loadedPerson.getEdges(Direction.OUT, "Photos")) {
  System.out.println( "Photo name: " + e.getVertex(Direction.IN).getProperty("name") );
}
```

To access the underlying edge list you have to use the Document Database API. Here's an example to swap the 10th photo with the last.

```
// REPLACE EDGE Photos
List<ODocument> photos = loadedPerson.getRecord().field("out_Photos");
photos.add(photos.remove(9));
```

From the [official documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Graph-Blueprints.html#ordered-edges).